# Transparent Node Background

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

How do i **programmatically** make a `Node`'s background transparent-(see through); I am currently playing with `AnchorPane` as a parent Node to other `ProgressIndicator` and other nodes as children, and i want them to stand out ? I tried with `Scene` and it wasn't close to what i wanted, any workaround?

lets say

```
// suppose i have a fake layout like this
    AnchorPane ap = new AnchorPane();

    ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator();
    ProgressIndicator pii = new ProgressIndicator();
    ProgressIndicator piii = new ProgressIndicator();
    ProgressIndicator piiii = new ProgressIndicator();
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(pi, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(piii, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(piiii, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(piiii, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(piii, 0.0);
    Circle circle = new Circle();
    circle.setRadius(50);
    circle.setFill(Color.RED);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(circle, 210.0);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(circle, 210.0);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(circle, 210.0);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(circle, 210.0);
    ap.getChildren().addAll(pi,pii,piii,circle,piiii);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(ap,500,500));
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    primaryStage.show();
```

My requirement here is to make my children `Nodes` stand out,without the white background of the `AnchorPane` -(so AnchorPane needs to be transparent), how do i achieve that?

Comment: What did you try? Does your code just have an AnchorPane as the root of Scene or are there child nodes in the AnchorPane as well? Please add the code which you tried, as transparency depends on `hierarchy` as well.

Comment: Sir @ItachiUchiha its a parent node with children i have given some sample something..,and also what do you mean by _as transparency depends on hierarchy as well_ does it's meaning really mean as it sounds?

Comment: May be my answer puts some light on my comment.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Everything including `Stage`, `Scene` and `Layout Containers` have their background color. So if you need a complete transparent background, you need to set `transparent fill` to each of these.

**For Stage**

```
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
```

**For Scene**

```
scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

**For Containers**

```
container.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
```

**For your code**

```
Scene scene = new Scene(ap,500,500);
scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
ap.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first understand how the JavaFX view hierarchy works. First, you have a `Stage`. In a stage, you can display a `Scene`. In a scene, you can embed a `Node`, which will typically be a pane or sorts, like a `BorderPane`. In that case, you should make the pane transparent, as it is the content of the scene of the stage.

Use `setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");`, or better yet: add that to a class in a css file, set that css file as the style sheet of the scene containing your `Node` and add the css class to the `styleClasses` of the Node.

Comment: Of course it is only [Regions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) whose background can be styled using CSS.

Comment: sorry didnt fully read your whole answer, but SIr, it doesnt work, i added my requirements in code sample you can check my edit or i don't get it?