# How to make translucent and ungeometrically shaped window in javafx?

Tags: javafx

Can somebody tell me how I can make translucent and ungeometrically shaped (any custom shape except geometric shapes like rectangle for ex- cloud shaped window) window in java fx. I tried it by setting the png image to the background of AnchorPane using css, but the whole AnchorPane is showing rectangular.

Comment: @user:5903534 pls read the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004893/transparent-node-background

Comment: Have you tried [translucent and shaped windows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html) with a [`JFXPanel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html)?