# How To Round the Corners of a JavaFX Popup

Tags: java, css, javafx, popup, popupwindow

I've seen a few posts about how to round the outer corners of anchorpanes and similar nodes, but
I need the functionality provided by popups, and therefore they're the only type of node I can use (or are by far the easiest to use in this case).

I know you can use CSS with a PopupControl to achieve this, but then I can't add nodes to the PopupControl through java classes. Conversely, I can add nodes to a Popup, but cannot apply a stylesheet to it.

Therefore, is there anyway to round the corners of a Popup? Or is there a way to consolidate/link a Popup and a CSS styled PopupControl, considering they both extend PopupWindow? If so, what would the CSS code look like (I'm new to CSS)?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: “I can’t add nodes to a `PoupControl` through Java classes”. It’s not clear what you mean by that.

Comment: See [this answer about  non rectangular stages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29029875/1155209).  Popup will be somewhat similar, though perhaps a Stage based solution might work better for you anyway.

Comment: @James_D If I wanted to add a VBox to a PopupControl, I'd have to do something like PopupControl pu = new PopupControl(); pu.getContent().add(new VBox()); But getContent() in the PopupControl class has private access.

Comment: What’s wrong with `getScene().setRoot(…)`?

Comment: @James_D Thats exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!